# URI scheme for wordpress

Tags: ios, wordpress, uri

I want to know if there's an [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) for Wordpress app, like there's for [faceboook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app) or for [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974610/how-do-i-open-a-users-twitter-profile-using-the-twitter-app-using-a-link-in-mob).
This helps inter-app communication [for iOS/Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)  and [for Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#DataTest)

EDIT: I'm not asking for my own customized scheme uris, but the one for [the wordpres.com official app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordpress/id335703880?mt=8).

Comment: @Liam I'm not asking for any recommendation. How is this different from asking for facebook uri schemes uses or any other app schemes like the many I have seen previously in SO with no complains?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your own uri scheme, its will be uniq for your app only (you can use bundle id for this) something like `appscheme://` by tapping on url like this `appscheme://additonal_data?data=1` you will be redirect to your app and can retrieve params in appDelegate

BUT

Starting at ios 9 you can use appGroups its more efficient method

[docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)

Comment: see the edit: I'm not looking for my own scheme but for the wordpress app one.